# Dialog from service not showing on lollipop when screen is locked

Tags: android, service, dialog, android-5.0-lollipop, samsung-mobile

I am trying to show a Dialog from service in onStartCommand method

```
private Dialog incomingCallDialog;

incomingCallDialog = new Dialog(MyService.this, R.style.PopupDialog);
        incomingCallDialog.setCancelable(false);
        incomingCallDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        incomingCallDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        incomingCallDialog.setContentView(view);

Handler delayHandler = new Handler();
        delayHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {                
                    incomingCallDialog.show();               
            }
        }, 100);
```

This code works fine in SamsungS5 which has Kitkat and when device is locked but it doesn't work on SamsungS6 which has lollipop 5.0.2 when device is locked.

The dialog is not showing at all in Lollipop when device is locked.

Answer (score 1):

Change TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT to TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY it should work

Comment: This wont help me getting touch from CustomViews

Comment: but now the user won't be able to answer his call without closing your dialog first

Comment: I am doing that programmatically :)