# Android -showing alert dialog from service when phone is locked

Tags: java, android, service, dialog, android-5.0-lollipop

Showing alert dialog on lock screen from service is my problem. when phone is on unlock state ,it shows nicely. Actually if phone is lock , it will just unlock phone and alert dialog will appears behind lock. Here is my code:

**Service.java:**

```
public static void popupDialog(String sender , String msg)
{
    final String senderName = sender;
    final String message = msg;
    Handler h = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
    h.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

            if (km.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode())
            {
                lockFlag = true;
                Log.d ("---popup","lock");
                powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                km = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                mKeyguardLock = km.newKeyguardLock("com.example.myapplication");
                mKeyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
                wl = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "com.example.myapplication");
                wl.acquire();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d ("---popup","unlock");
            }
            final View view = View.inflate(context.getApplicationContext(),R.layout.popup, null);
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setView(view);
            final ImageView ImageView1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
            final TextView TextView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
            final TextView TextViewSender = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextViewSender);
            TextViewSender.setText (senderName+":");
            final TextView TextView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView2);
            TextView2.setText (message);
            final EditText EditText1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.EditText1);

            final ImageButton ImageButton1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton1);
            ImageButton1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                /*do some task*/
                    }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder1.create();
            alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
            alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

I just want to show alert dialog on lock.

**EDITED :** I use Android Lolipop, and after read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961858/dialog-from-service-not-showing-on-lollipop-when-screen-is-locked)  , I used *TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY* instead of *TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT*. In this situation, I cannot type on EditText or even close dialog.

Comment: The post you are talking about has comment which say it is fixed by `TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR`. Did you try that?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I used it and it was worked but I should check on lower android API.

Comment: Yeah , it work with TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the type to `TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR`

Change

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

to

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR);
```

**Update:**

**`TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`** - Window type: system window, such as low power alert. These windows are always on top of application windows. In multiuser systems shows only on the owning user's window.
*Constant Value: 2003 (0x000007d3)*

**`TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR`** - Window type: internal system error windows, appear on top of everything they can. In multiuser systems shows only on the owning user's window.
*Constant Value: 2010 (0x000007da)*

More info is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR)

Comment: So, What's different between TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT and TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR?

Comment: `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` and `TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR` are deprecated. Ror non-system apps. Use `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` instead.